# Unable to determine the format type of API Response

Tags: c#

I'm trying to parse a array almost like a JSON type like response from an API.

Notice that I can't change or modify the structure of this response.

Maybe someone has an idea of what type is this.
I mention that I've searched on google and failed to find a concrete answer to my question.

Here is the response that comes as a ***string type***:

```
[
  {
    name=David,
    age=7
  },
  {
    name=John,
    age=7
  },
  ..
  ..
  ..
]
```

Thanks

Comment: Which language/environment do you want to use to parse this data?

Comment: I want to parse this in C#/Visual Studio

Comment: Is this coming back as a string?  Have you tried using Newtonsoft's Json.Net to parse it?

Comment: @Jesse Newtonsoft parser won't be happy with the `=` signs

Comment: Is it a typo that there are no quotes around your strings?  If not, and the response is coming back that way then I'm afraid that there is no easy way, and you'll need to manually parse.  Also that's not actually json syntax, so disregard my first comment.

Comment: @Piou - You're right, I noticed that after the fact, the missing quotes will cause a problem too.  He's going to have to do something manual here.

Comment: It is a string, I've tried to parse it but the Newtonsoft fills them with null instead. I think because they don't contain the standard format: _,,"property" : "value"_

Answer (score 2):

It looks a little like JSON, but it is not valid JSON. I guess you'll have two approaches to deal with this:

1. Create your own custom parser.
2. transform your input file to JSON and then use your favorite JSON parser.

I think I would use the former.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 2):

You could do some replacements in the result to turn it in to valid `JSON` then use `Json.net` to parse, but that may prove to be just as complicated as writing your own parser depending on the possible data that you could get back.  If this is the standard response then you could add a quote at the beginning of each line, add a quote before the commas, and then replace the = with `":"`.  After doing that it it would be legal `JSON`.  If the data varies too much though I think I'd recommend a custom parser where you could program for all variations, as my proposed solution isn't very flexible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!